# How do I obtain, generate or convert a YUV image file?

Tags: images, yuv

I'm trying to obtain an YUV image file. The answers on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3644501/where-can-i-obtain-a-raw-yuv-file) refer only to video files. I have found some YUV images on [this page](http://www.sunrayimage.com/examples.html), but it doesn't specify the image depth.

Alternatively, how do I convert a `.jpg` image to YUV?

Comment: [YUV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YUV) is not a file format, but rather a [color space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_space). What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @ThatBrazilianGuy YUV is technically a color space, but also refers to the family of YUV-encoded data formats for raw images and video.

Comment: try imagemagic https://www.imagemagick.org/script/formats.php

Comment: `convert test.jpg test.uyvy`
this question seems clear now
https://www.imagemagick.org/script/formats.php

Comment: @Tog, why it closed? The question is clear.

Comment: the link for the images is dead :(

Answer (score 6):

[ffmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org) supports a large number of YUV pixel formats (run `ffmpeg -pix_fmts` to see all).
You can convert any input file to a YUV file with:

```
ffmpeg -i input.jpg -f rawvideo -pix_fmt yuv420p output.yuv
```

The same applies to video too.

The full list of YUV pixel formats:

```
Name                   Components   Bits/Pixel
==============================================
yuv420p                3            12
yuv422p                3            16
yuv444p                3            24
yuv410p                3             9
yuv411p                3            12
yuvj420p               3            12
yuvj422p               3            16
yuvj444p               3            24
yuv440p                3            16
yuvj440p               3            16
yuva420p               4            20
yuv420p16le            3            24
yuv420p16be            3            24
yuv422p16le            3            32
yuv422p16be            3            32
yuv444p16le            3            48
yuv444p16be            3            48
yuv420p9be             3            13
yuv420p9le             3            13
yuv420p10be            3            15
yuv420p10le            3            15
yuv422p10be            3            20
yuv422p10le            3            20
yuv444p9be             3            27
yuv444p9le             3            27
yuv444p10be            3            30
yuv444p10le            3            30
yuv422p9be             3            18
yuv422p9le             3            18
yuva420p9be            4            22
yuva420p9le            4            22
yuva422p9be            4            27
yuva422p9le            4            27
yuva444p9be            4            36
yuva444p9le            4            36
yuva420p10be           4            25
yuva420p10le           4            25
yuva422p10be           4            30
yuva422p10le           4            30
yuva444p10be           4            40
yuva444p10le           4            40
yuva420p16be           4            40
yuva420p16le           4            40
yuva422p16be           4            48
yuva422p16le           4            48
yuva444p16be           4            64
yuva444p16le           4            64
yuva444p               4            32
yuva422p               4            24
yuv420p12be            3            18
yuv420p12le            3            18
yuv420p14be            3            21
yuv420p14le            3            21
yuv422p12be            3            24
yuv422p12le            3            24
yuv422p14be            3            28
yuv422p14le            3            28
yuv444p12be            3            36
yuv444p12le            3            36
yuv444p14be            3            42
yuv444p14le            3            42
yuvj411p               3            12
```